# Filling in specific fields in a form on a website [Greasemonkey / Javascript]

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm fairly new to scripting, but I was looking for a way to automatically fill in certain fields on a certain webpage on a click of a button.

So far I have managed this:

```
//Adding a button
x=0
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value=x;
input.onclick= fillValuesInTextBoxes;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:120px;right:40px;");
document.body.appendChild(input); 


function fillValuesInTextBoxes()
{
    document.getElementById('username').value="MyUserName"
    document.getElementById('password').value="MyPassWord"
}
```

It seems I'm off with the Ids or anything else, but I can't figure out what exactly. The website I've taken for references is Darkthone login page (See include).

Maybe somebody could tell me how to find the propper Id or Tag of each field?

And how to add certain input to those fields in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

"(See include)" - there is no `@include` shown in the snippet, also no `@run-at`. If you don't get any button at all, it might be that `<body>` isn't initialized yet.

For error checking put your code inside a

```
try{
  // here the code...
}
catch(e)
{
  console.log(e);
}
```

Then open the console in your browser. (Ctrl+Shift+k in Firefox, Chrome is similar)

In the console you can also inspect elements. Rightclick on an element and select "inspect" in the context menu. You will find, that the "Username or Email" `<input>` has the id "user_login" for example.

```
document.getElementById('email_address').value = email;
document.querySelector('input[type=password]').value = password;
```